# sample rc file for splint

Tags: c, embedded, splint

I am using splint for code checking, and it is throwing out a huge number of warnings. Some of them, I guess can be ignored. I am in the process of creating the .splintrc by trial and error.

My question,

Is there some sample .splintrc file that can be used?

I am using splint for C code, written for a multi-tasking embedded system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the greatest of help but I think that you need to provide a bit more information about the type of error messages that you are getting and the target processor/compiler that you are using.  The different compilers for embedded target processors all have their own syntax to provide their specific functionality (interrupt processing, transferring to supervisor modes and hardware interfacing are examples)

I have tried to use splint on the MSP430 under IAR and gave up because of the number of warnings and errors that it was throwing when it tried to process the compiler supplied hardware interface definition files.  I bit the bullet and purchased Gimpel LINT which came with some configuration files that I could modify to support the precise flavour of compiler and processor I was using.

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with Splint, but have worked with PC-Lint, and this was my experience as well.  Without the compiler configuration files, the lint tool will throw a ton of errors.

You will need to find or create compiler-specific configurations files for your compiler informing the linting tool of the special (non-standard) C constructs and macros that it uses which should be ignored by the linting tool, or you will continue to throw tons of errors.

It is worth the effort, however.  Linting your code will help you find errors now instead of during testing when they are harder to find and much more expensive to fix.